# Item inside an object returns as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I passed an object to my component as a prop. I can access it and it returns it as an object but when I try to access an item out of the object which I'm sure it exist it says undefined.

When I run this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { CardSection } from './common';

class ListItem extends Component {
    render() {
        const { titleStyle } = styles;
        console.log(this.props.library);
        console.log(this.props.library.title);

        return (
            <CardSection>
                <Text style={titleStyle}>{this.props.library.title}</Text>
            </CardSection>
        );
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
{…}
​
    index: 0
​
    item: Object { id: 0, title: "Webpack", description: "Webpack is a module bundler. It packs CommonJs/AMD modules i. e. for the browser. Allows to split your codebase into multiple bundles, which can be loaded on demand." }

undefined
```

This result for the last `console.log()` is in the bottom.

This is the component from where I am passing the library object:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class LibraryList extends Component {
   renderItem(library) {
        return <ListItem library={library} />;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList
            data={this.props.libraries}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={library => library.id.toString()}
            />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ libraries: state.libraries });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LibraryList);
```

Check the full code here: https://github.com/ceerees12/tech_stack

Comment: You use `props.title` in one place and `props.library.title` in another. Are you sure you didn't just confuse the two? From your output it seems like it needs to be `this.props.library.title`

Comment: Can you share the component from where you are passing the library object, moreover I think as the title is inside the library object that is why you are getting error

Comment: No, I'm sure I didn't confuse between two. I looked over the whole code several times before posting here I can give you the whole code if needed.

Comment: @FahadRehman I edited the question you can check it now

Comment: Check the full code here: https://github.com/ceerees12/tech_stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `renderItem={this.renderItem}` into `renderItem={() =>this.renderItem(library)}`

Comment: I get `'library' is not defined`

Comment: Can you try then to console log `this.props.libraries` in your LibraryList component? Chances are this is undefined, i.e. you don't get data from your redux store

Comment: No, it returns as an object exactly what I wanted. I am new to React Native and Redux, can you check my code at Github? Please

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing `title` in the component, if you pass the prop `title` in your `ListItem` component then you will be able to access `this.props.title`and if the `title` is in `library` prop then it should `this.props.library.title`.

Comment: Doesn't work I tried passing `library.title` instead of `library` to `ListItem` but still it returns as undefined.